# uniqueness of solutions in the future

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm asked to proof this:
If we have $$f:\mathbb R^d\rightarrow\mathbb R^d, f \in C^1$$
verifying:$$\ f(0)=0 \ $$ $$\ \langle p,f(p)\rangle \leq0 ,\ \forall p \in \mathbb R^d$$
then  the initial value problem  $$ \left \{
      \begin{matrix} 
         x'=f(x)\\
         x(0)=0\\
      \end{matrix}
   \right .\}$$
has a unique solution in the future.
Any answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is $C^1$, existence and uniqueness of a local solution is guaranteed by the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem (a.k.a. Picard's theorem,...) What you are asked to prove is that the solution is defined on $[0,\infty)$. For this it is enough to prove that the solution does not blow-up, that is, it is bounded on any finite interval $[0,T]$ (with a bound that may depend on $T$.) Let $x(t)$ be the solutuion. Then
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\|x(t)\|^2=\frac{d}{dt}\langle x(t),x(t)\rangle=2\,\langle x(t), x'(t)\rangle=2\,\langle x(t), f(x(t))\rangle\le0.
$$
Thus, $\|x(t)\|^2$ is decreasing, and $\|x(t)\|\le\|x(0)\|$ for all $t$ for which the solution is defined.